# Changing the position of a content of a button C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

[image]

Here's my button. How can I make the content to be higher without changing the height?

Comment: `Padding=0` or whatever other value.

Comment: I know. But I want to keep this height.

Comment: And again set the `Padding`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify `negative value for padding` from `top` (Choose the value as per your requirement) -

```
<Button Content="I want this to be higher" Padding="0,-3,0,0"/>
```

Comment: It's a weird conversation if you remove your comments.

Comment: @Silvermind - Ideal solution would be to increase height but OP later updated question that he can't change the height. So, i remove my comment since it holds no meaning after updation.

Comment: Yes, but your current answer was the right answer all along, regardless of the height. +1 anyhow.